# Send response and get request after every execution of statement in the views.py function - Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, text-to-speech

Is there any way to send response to html template when the statement executes in the function everytime ?

```
def name(request):
    tts = _TTS()
    tts.speak("May I know your first name ?") #send response to index.html after this speak() execution.
    tts.speak("May I know your last name ?") #send again response to index.html after this speak() execution.
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

I want to notify the client side  everytime when the speak() execute. what would be the best way to deal with it ?